# Key (id)=() is still referenced from table for onetoone field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I have 1 to 1 field in my model where i would still need to link the data with other while i delete them on the other table.In my view i am deleting model 2 instance while that is deleted i am setting the completed to Tue but it is throwing error.

**models.py**

```py
class Model1(models.Model):
    model_2_attribute = models.OnetoOneField('Model2' on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    completed = model.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's missing a default value or the option for the `model_2_attribute` to be null. If you delete `Model2` then `Model1` would have an invalid relation.

**Option 1** would be to set the default value to null. If you delete `Model2` then the `model_2_attribute` will be None.

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    model_2_attribute = models.OneToOneField('Model2', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

**Option 2** would be to move the `completed` field into `Model2` and do not delete it. Instead only set the field to True.

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    model_2_attribute = models.OneToOneField('Model2', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class Model2(models.Model):
    # your fields
    completed = model.BooleanField(default=False)
```

You can then filter for non-completed objects like:

```
qs = Model1.objects.filter(model_2_attribute__completed=False)
```